# Spring MVC binding request parameters

Tags: spring-mvc

I wrote a spring-mvc controller method to get an array of values in the request parameter.The method looks like below

```
/**
 Trying to get the value for request param foo which passes multiple values

**/
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void performActionXX(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response,
                        @RequestParam("foo") String[] foo) {

......
......

}
```

The above method works fine when the request url is in below format

```
...?foo=1234&foo=0987&foo=5674.
```

However when the request url is in below format the server returns 400 error

```
...?foo[0]=1234&foo[1]=0987&foo[2]=5674
```

Any idea how to fix the method to cater to the second format request url?

Comment: why do you want to do it this way ? "foo[0]=1234&foo[1]=0987&foo[2]=5674" and not the other way? any special reason?

Comment: I don't have the control over the request url

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `@RequestParam`. What you can do is implement and register your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to perform to resolve request parameters like

```
...?foo[0]=1234&foo[1]=0987&foo[2]=5674
```

into an array. You can always checkout the code of [`RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.html) to see how Spring does it.

**Note that I recommend you change how the client creates the URL.** 
The server is supposed to define an API and the client is meant to follow it, that's why we have the 400 Bad Request status code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue using the request.getParameterMap().Below is code.

```
Map<String,String> parameterMap=  request.getParameterMap();
    for(String key :parameterMap.keySet()){
        if(key.startsWith("nameEntry")){
            nameEntryLst.add(request.getParameter(key));
        }
    }
```